# Show that there is an efficient zero knowledge proof for any language $L \in NP$

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, complexity, soundness

Let $(P,V)$ be an efficient zero-knowledge interactive proof for some language $A \in NP$ that is $(T,\epsilon)-\text{sound}$ and $(T,\epsilon)-\text{ZK}$.

I want to show that for every language $L$ that is reducible to $A$ there is also such an efficient zero-knowledge interactive proof $(P_2, V_2)$ which is also $(T,\epsilon)-\text{sound}$ and $(T,\epsilon)-\text{ZK}$.

Well, I am not sure how exactly to start to describe such $(P_2, V_2)$, but maybe I don't understand this completely since it seems there is only one straightforward way.

Since $L$ is reducible to $A$, then there is a Levin reduction from $L$ to $A$. Namely, there is a polynomial algorithm $R$ such that $R(x) \in A \leftrightarrow x \in A$, and there is a polynomial algorithm $W$ that maps a witness $w$ for $x \in L$ to the witness $W(x,w)$ for $R(x) \in A$.

My idea was to take the proof system $(P,V)$ and for the input $x$ apply $R(x)$ to simulate the original zero-knowledge proof for $A$.

However, it seems too trivial to me. Moreover, in this way I only get $(T-|R|,\epsilon)-\text{sound}$ and $(T-|R|,\epsilon)-\text{ZK}$, since I need to run the algorithm $R$.

Help Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Although the running times of the honest prover and verifier do increase by the running time of $R$, this (somewhat counterintuitively) does not affect the concrete bounds for soundness and ZK (at least how they are usually defined).

Note that $T$-soundness does not really make sense for a *proof* system, since it is sound against even unbounded cheating provers. However, it does make sense for an *argument* system, and here we don’t really “lose” the reduction $R$’s runtime: any $T$-time cheating prover $P_2^*$ for some instance $x \notin L$ is *itself* a $T$-time cheating prover for the instance $R(x) \notin A$, because it fools the verifier $V$ (for language $A$) without doing any additional computation. The latter does not exist by assumption, so neither does the former.

Similar reasoning holds for ZK: a $T$-time cheating verifier $V_2^*$ for some instance $x\in L$ is itself a $T$-time cheating verifier for $R(x) \in A$, because it plays the role of $V$ in talking to $P$. So, we don’t need any additional computation to “gain knowledge” from an interaction with $P$ about $R(x)$.

Comment: thanks! Could you clarify a little bit how to practically construct $(P_2, V_2)$? It is still a little bit in the air for me. Namely, when exactly in the proof $(P V)$ I apply $R$ and $W$?

Comment: $V_2=V \circ R$, i.e., $V_2(x)$ just runs $V$ on $R(x)$. $P_2$ is defined similarly.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Your answer was very helpful!